# Surprising Summation (2): $\frac14 \sum_{i=1}^{2n}i(2n-i+1)=\sum_{i=1}^n i^2$

Tags: summation

Show that

> $$\frac14 \sum_{i=1}^{2n}i(2n-i+1)=\sum_{i=1}^n i^2$$

without expanding the summation to its closed-form solution, i.e. $\dfrac 16n(n+1)(2n+1)$ or equivalent.

E.g., if $n=5$, then

$$\frac 14 \bigg[\;1(10) + 2(9)+ 3(8)+\cdots+10(1)\;\bigg]=1^2+2^2+3^2+4^2+5^2$$

*Background as requested:*
The summands for both equations are not the same but the results are the same. The challenge here is to transform LHS into RHS without solving the summation. It seems like an interesting challenge. If you like this question, please vote to reopen it. Thank you!

Comment: I think pairing the terms as Gauss did for the triangle number might work...

Comment: Have reworded and shortened the question for greater clarity.

Comment: I fail to see what's surprising about this really.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD - You must be a genius!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\require{cancel}\begin{align}
\frac14\sum_{i=1}^{2n}i(2n-i+1)
&=\frac14\sum_{i=1}^{2n}\sum_{j=i}^{2n}i\\
&=\frac14\sum_{j=1}^{2n}\sum_{i=1}^j i
&& (1\le i\le j\le 2n)\\
&=\frac 14\sum_{j=1}^{2n}\binom {j+1}2\\
&=\frac14\sum_{r=1}^{n}\binom {2r}2+\binom{2r+1}2\\
&=\frac14\sum_{r=1}^n(2r)^2\\
&=\sum_{r=1}^nr^2
=\sum_{i=1}^ni^2\qquad\blacksquare
\end{align}$$

This solution requires prior knowledge of the result for the sum of integers but does **not** require prior knowledge of the result for the sum of squares (i.e. $C$).

Comment: +1 Nice. Suggestion (if you want to avoid the combinations): $\sum_{i=1}^{2j}i + \sum_{i=1}^{2j-1}i = 1 + \sum_{i=2}^{2j}i + \sum_{i=1}^{2j-1}i = 1 + \sum_{i=1}^{2j-1}(i+1) + \sum_{i=1}^{2j-1}i = 1 + \sum_{i=1}^{2j-1}(2i+1) = 1 + 3 + 5 + \dots + (4j-1) = (2j)^2$

Answer (score 3):

Notice that $2n - i + 1 = \sum_{k = 1}^{2n - i + 1} 1$, therefore, by changing the summation order of $i$ and $k$, 
\begin{align}
& \sum_{i = 1}^{2n}i(2n - i + 1) \\
= & \sum_{i = 1}^{2n}\sum_{k = 1}^{2n - i + 1} i \\
= & \sum_{k = 1}^{2n}\sum_{i = 1}^{2n - k + 1} i \\
= & \sum_{k = 1}^{2n}\frac{(2n - k + 2 )(2n - k + 1)}{2} \\
= & \frac{1}{2}\sum_{k = 1}^{2n}(2n - k + 1)^2 + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{k = 1}^{2n}(2n - k + 1) \\
= & \frac{1}{2}\sum_{k = 1}^{2n}k^2 + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{k = 1}^{2n}k
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks for posting an answer. Can you complete it so that it ends up as RHS? Can you also show that it's the sum of squares without doing the full expansion? If so, then we can get to the closed form straight away.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac14 \sum_{i=1}^{2n}i(2n+1-i)= \frac{2n+1}{4}\sum_{i=1}^{2n}i - \frac{1}{4}\sum_{i=1}^{2n}i^2$$
$$=\frac{2n+1}{4}\cdot \frac{2n\left(2n+1\right)}{2} - \frac{1}{4}\frac{\left(2n\right)\left(2n+1\right)\left(4n+1\right)}{6}$$
$$=\frac{2n+1}{4}\left[n(2n+1) - \frac{n(4n+1)}{3}\right]$$
$$=\frac{2n+1}{12}\left[3n(2n+1) - n(4n+1)\right] = \frac{2n+1}{12}\left[2n^2 + 2n\right]$$
$$= \frac16n\left(2n+1\right)(n+1)= \sum_{i=1}^ni^2$$

Comment: It should be $$\frac{2n+1}{12}[2n^2\color{red}{+}2n]$$ and that should  make the non-equality equal!

Comment: @hypergeometric, I had a typo. You're right

Comment: :) Thanks for posting an answer. Can you show that it's the sum of squares without doing the full expansion? If so, then we can get to the closed form straight away.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how acceptable this answer is, because it uses induction and the triangle numbers identity of Gauss. Still, it doesn't directly use the sum of squares formula, so here goes. For abbreviation let $a_{i, n} = i(2n-i+1)$. Also let $S_n = \sum_{i=1}^{2n}a_{i, n}$ Now notice the following inductive identity:

$$S_{n + 1} = \sum_{i=1}^{2n + 2}a_{i, n + 1} = \sum_{i=1}^{2n}a_{i, n} + \sum_{i=1}^{2n}2i + 2n + 2 + (2n + 1)2 = S_n + 2n(2n + 1) + 2n + 2 + (2n + 1)2 = S_n + 4(n + 1)^2$$

Combine this with the base case of $S_1 = 4$ and you have an inductive proof of your identity.

Comment: Thank you for posting an answer. Please see the reworded question.

Comment: Yes I had a feeling that induction and the triangle inequality was "cheating". Are you confident it can be done by changing limits? Any ideas?

Comment: Every solution adds additional perspective to the question so your contribution is appreciated. Have just posted a solution using the change of summation limits.

Comment: Nice solution, some cool ideas in there.